# Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRMessaging'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to follow the guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image

I create a new project In Xcode and with my app project open, navigate to File > Add Packages and then I enter  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk. After I went to New > Target > Notification Service Extension (embedded this new target into the original target) and pasted in `NotificationService.m`:

```
@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];
    
    // Modify the notification content here...
    self.bestAttemptContent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]", self.bestAttemptContent.title];
    
    // Call FIRMessaging extension helper API.
    [[FIRMessaging extensionHelper] populateNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent
                                             withContentHandler:contentHandler];
    
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

@end
```

I am now getting `Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRMessaging' in NotificationService.m`.
What did I forget?

Comment: did you include Firebase pod file to the notification service target ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Podfile, use code for pod file

```
 platform :ios, '11.0'
def same_pods
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
target 'Project' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase', "~> 7.0"
    target 'NotificationServiceExt' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
  
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64 i386"
      end
    end
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
      project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
  
end
```

Install the pod file and, in NotificationService file

```
#import "NotificationService.h"
@import Firebase;
@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    // Modify the notification content here as you wish
    self.bestAttemptContent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
    self.bestAttemptContent.title];
  // Call FIRMessaging extension helper API.
    [[FIRMessaging extensionHelper] populateNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent withContentHandler:contentHandler];
   
   

}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

@end
```